# Как преобразовать JSON во фрейм данных?

Tags: python, json, pandas, оптимизация, анализ-данных

Есть JSON cо 100k строками вида:

```
[{'dimensions': [{'name': '2021-04-18'},
   {'name': None},
   {'name': None},
   {'name': '1684110345'},
   {'name': '/catalog/shchetki_skrebki_avtomobilnye/43163/',
    'favicon': 'site.ru'}],
  'metrics': [1.0]},

 {'dimensions': [{'name': '2021-04-18'},
   {'name': None},
   {'name': None},
   {'name': '16766514821'},
   {'name': '/catalog/obogrevateli/tip-konvektor/', 'favicon': site.ru'}],
  'metrics': [1.0]},

 {'dimensions': [{'name': '2021-04-18'},
   {'name': None},
   {'name': None},
   {'name': '1539634499435983'},
   {'name': '/catalog/', 'favicon': site .ru}],
  'metrics': [1.0]},…..
```

Нужно его преобразовать во фрейм данных вида:

'2021-04-18' | None | None | '16766514821' | /catalog/obogrevateli/tip-konvektor/ |1.0

Написал цикл, чтобы распарсить, но 100к строк обрабатывается час:

```
dict_data = {}
for i in range(0, len(result)-1):
  
    dict_data[i] = {
                    'date':result[i]["dimensions"][0]["name"],
                    'lastsignUTMCampaign':result[i]["dimensions"][1]["name"],
                    'lastsignUTMSource':result[i]["dimensions"][2]["name"],
                    'userID':result[i]["dimensions"][3]["name"],
                    'startURLPath':result[i]["dimensions"][4]["name"],
                    'visits':result[i]["metrics"][0]
         }
    dict_keys = dict_data[0].keys()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index',columns=dict_keys)
df
```

Подскажите, как можно ускорить этот процесс?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте собрать все данные в один большой список списков (строк фрейма) и потом создать из этого списка один фрейм - одной командой:

```
cols = ["date", "lastsignUTMCampaign", "lastsignUTMSource", "userID", "startURLPath", "visits"]

df = pd.DataFrame([[x.get("name") for x in  d["dimensions"]] + d["metrics"] 
                   for d in data], 
                  columns=cols)
```

результат:

```
In [298]: df
Out[298]:
         date lastsignUTMCampaign lastsignUTMSource            userID                                   startURLPath  visits
0  2021-04-18                None              None        1684110345  /catalog/shchetki_skrebki_avtomobilnye/43163/     1.0
1  2021-04-18                None              None       16766514821           /catalog/obogrevateli/tip-konvektor/     1.0
2  2021-04-18                None              None  1539634499435983                                      /catalog/     1.0
```